# Post picture to Facebook using Python

Tags: python, http, curl, urllib2, urllib

How can I post an image to Facebook using Python?

Comment: I think this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009441/facebook-python-sdk-post-to-wall-attachment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the facebook provided [Python SDK](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) to upload photos using an oauth key.
Once you get the oauth key, you can upload a picture with [GraphAPI.put_object()](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-object):

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
photo = open("picture.jpg", "rb")
graph.put_object("me", "photos", message="You can put a caption here", source=photo.read())
photo.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Python SDK is discontinued now. Will not work. Need to use Javascript / PHP / iOS / Android APIs

Answer (score 2):

Fresh links of Facebook Platform Python SDK

- https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/facebook-sdk

http://pythonforfacebook.com

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this library: https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/

Comment: The repo link is no more available, this time right now I check it.